# Мне нужна Ваша помощь в поиске ошибки

Tags: javascript, type-error

Я не понимаю что не так.

```
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;
const CHAT_ID = '-*************';
const URL_API = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/sendMessage`;
const success = document.getElementById('success');

document.getElementById('tg').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let message = `<b>Заявка с сайта!</b>\n`;
  message += `<b>Отправитель: </b> ${this.name.value}\n`;
  message += `<b>Телефон: </b> ${this.tel.value}\n`;
  message += `<b>Имя пользователя: </b> ${this.comment.value}`;

  axios
    .post(URL_API, {
      chat_id: CHAT_ID,
      parse_mode: 'html',
      text: message,
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.name.value = '';
      this.tel.value = '';
      this.comment.value = '';
      success.innerHTML = 'Сообщение отправлено!';
      success.style.display = 'block';
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.warn(err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      console.log('Отправили!');
    });
});
```

Ошибка:
tg.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at tg.js:4:15

Comment: А откуда process возьмётся в браузере-то?

Comment: Да и даже если его откуда-то взять, работать код всё равно не будет, потому что API телеграма нельзя использовать в браузере

Comment: @andreymal да я вот и не знаю. браузер не поодерживает import process from 'process'; что делать без понятия (((

Comment: process есть в nodejs. Часть кода надо перенести на сервер. Или просто в переменную **TOKEN** положите токен бота в явном виде(хотя это очень не безопасно)

Comment: @Роман ну для начала осознать, а что вы вообще делаете, потому что сейчас вы, кажется, делаете какую-то дичь, пытаясь реализовать работу телеграм-бота в браузере

Comment: @andreymal я пытаюсь сделать, что бы после заполнения  формы на сайте приходило смс на телеграм бот

Comment: @Роман и из браузера это не сработает, потому что см. второй комментарий, вам нужен сервер

Comment: @SwaD да, и вот по этому я и спрятал TOKEN в файл .env

Comment: @Роман ...и одновременно с этим вы пытаетесь запихнуть токен в браузер, чтобы все пользователи могли вытащить токен из браузера и полностью управлять вашим ботом. Вы всё-таки не понимаете, что вы делаете

Comment: @andreymal так помогите мне пожалуйста. я не знаю как мне быть. я новичок в этих делах

Comment: Так... Ваш сайт должен отправить сообщение на свой сервер, а тот в свою очередь должен отправить сообщение в бота. env живет только на сервере.

Comment: @Роман реализовывать работу с телеграм-ботом на сервере, а не в браузере. Браузер вообще ничего не должен знать про телеграм, он должен только отправить запрос на сервер и всё

Comment: @andreymal я Вас понял. спасибо!

Comment: @SwaD спасибо Вам!